# Filter through a response in a nested entity spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I set up the entity relationship with Product - Cart this way:

**Product.java**

```
@Entity(name="Product")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int amount;
    private String unit;
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn()
    private Cart cart;
}
```

**Cart.java**

```
@Entity(name="Cart")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cart implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy="cart",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Product> shoppingList  = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean payed = true;
}
```

What my task is to make a post request to  **localhost:8080/cart** without a request body and the response should be this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "shoppingList": [
    {
      "productId": 0,
      "amount": 0
    }
  ],
  "payed": true
}
```

So as you can see, I somehow need to put to the shoppingList only the **productId**  and the **amount** **(both are coming from product** where I set up the entity relationship)

Thats how I make the POST request:

```
 @PostMapping()
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Cart addProduct() {
        return new Cart(this.service.create());
    }
```

And this is my service where the logic should go:

```
 @Override
    public Cart create() {
        Cart c = new Cart();
        c.setPayed(false);
        return this.repository.save(c);
    }
```

That's where I need help to somehow make a **c.setShoppingList( ??? )** to get **id** and the **amount** from product but **only these two**

Comment: IMO serializing entities directly to the client is a bad and potentially dangerous practice. It mixes concerns (entity concern=how to persist this thing, DTO concern=how to serialize this thing) and can potentially leak information (someone adds a field to an entity that should not be visible by clients, e.g. email, password, but this entity is serialized and the email leaks). I know it is convenient and used all over the place, but I still believe it's bad. In your case I would create a DTO for the Cart containing a DTO for the Product with only the required fields.

Comment: Having commented about DTOs, you may want to look at the capabilities offered by the serialization library; it's probably Jackson so check out `@JsonIgnore` and, in general, how can it limit the fields sent to the client e.g. [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation). Jackson is very rich, you may find other ways more applicable to your needs.

Comment: you can create a response object (java class as per the response json) and use getter setters return it as a response entity.